# Delete multiple Items from a List of Id's using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to delete multiple Ids from a **List** of Ids.

```
public IHttpActionResult Delete(List<string> IDs)
{
    DealBazarEntities.Restaurants.RemoveRange(IDs);
    DealBazarEntities.SaveChanges();
}
```

But `RemoveRange` does not allow multiple ids , it expect only `List<entities>`.

Yes, I know that , if I send list of entities to server instead of sending List of ids , Then I can easily accomplish  this. But I don't like that.

Again, I don't want to use `foreach` loop to loop through every Ids.

Comment: `DealBazarEntities.Restaurants.RemoveRange(DealBazarEntities.Restaurants.Where(r => IDs.Contains(r.ID)));`

Comment: Wow... It's working like a charm.... Thanks. You saved my lots of time again. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the answer of `Stephen Muecke`'s answer given into comment section in the question , the solution is :

```
DealBazarEntities.Restaurants.RemoveRange
(DealBazarEntities.Restaurants.Where(r => IDs.Contains(r.ID)));
```

Comment: Good answer, but note that when I profiled this, it executed an initial SELECT and then separate DELETE statements per matched ID, rather than one DELETE that used IN. So it's not quite as efficient as it could be.

Comment: @JohnnyHK I think you can execute raw sql command from EF in this scenario.